# Worthington jets explanation: fluid phenomenon

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, soft-question

**I don't understand the reason behind the formation of Worthington jets**

I've been reading a bit about Worthington jets [Video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4D6mFScKfc), this phenomenon is caused when something is thrown to the water as we all have seen in swimming pools. This is also caused when a bubble comes from the bottom of a liquid and burst at the liquid interface [Video 2](https://youtu.be/-OqrZG-EBaQ?t=1m57s).

Destin(SmarterEveryDay), a science youtuber demonstrated this effect [Video 3](https://youtu.be/-XNDM4eAn1U)
in his channel , but I don't understand the explanation of this effect, he claims at [0:53](https://youtu.be/-XNDM4eAn1U?t=53s):

> Destin: *A cavity opens up and it's air and all that air has nowhere to go, so it slaps back together because there is a discontinuity in pressure*

I don't understand what does he mean by "discontinuity in pressure"

I've been reading at this article *STEPHANGEKLE AND J.M.GORDILLO, Generation and Breakup of Worthington Jets After Cavity Collapse* [[5]](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.5154v1.pdf). There is a really  interesting picture in page 5:

[image: Article Figure 2]

Here it's shown that suddenly when the two cavities separate, two jets appear in different directions, the article only says in page 3:

> *after impact a large cavity is created beneath the surface which
>   subsequently collapses about halfway due to the hydrostatic pressure from the liquid
>   bulk.*

There is no information about the reason behind the generation of the Worthington jet, it seems to me that there is something like a restoring force when the two cavities separate.

I understand much less about  [Video 2](https://youtu.be/-OqrZG-EBaQ?t=1m57s), it seems to me that when the bubble explodes it generates some kind of wave that meet in the bottom of the bubble.

I just wanna get a rough understanding on the generation of this phenomena. Any help clarifying something related with the phenomenon is appreciated