# By what mechanism is a Worthington jet generated when a hydrophilic sphere impacts a body of water?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, collision

In this video
(https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=yblbsylowkY&feature=youtu.be), the impacts of a hydrophilic and a hydrophobic sphere into water are compared, showing two different Worthington jets generated during the collision.

My understanding for the hydrophobic sphere’s jet is that it is generated by the collapse of the underwater air cavity created during the impact.

By what mechanism is the Worthington jet generated in the case of the hydrophilic sphere?

Comment: There is one post on this forum about the Worthington jet on https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/192860/worthington-jets-explanation-fluid-phenomenon and related paper on  https://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.5154v1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

As you see in the video, two jets are generated in the hydrophilic case. The first jet is generated due to the impact of the sphere onto the surface. This jet is generated when the sphere has not fully submerged. Once the sphere fully submerges, the additional fluid displaced by the sphere results in the formation of a second jet. More details are available in this [reference](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/67750).